# Inheritance of styling elements between div wrappers

Tags: html, css

I developed a pure-CSS expanding menu many years ago (about 2011) which I am now applying to a new site with some of the newer CSS functionality. It achieves almost everything that I want.

[image]

However, my CSS appears to have a lot of redundancy, so I have been trying to clean it up using divs as wrappers, and styling each div with the elements common to each.

This process has highlighted a deficiency in my understanding of CSS.

The HTML of one parent menu item, or "block", is as follows:

```
<div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menuBlockOf4">
        <div class="menuButtonFirst"><a href="about_us.html">About us</a></div>

        <div class="submenuWrapper">
            <div class="submenuButton"><a href="about_us-mission_and_vision.html">Mission and vision</a></div>
            <div class="submenuButton"><a href="about_us-philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></div>
            <div class="submenuButton"><a href="about_us-system.html">System</a></div>
            <div class="submenuButtonFinal"><a href="about_us-our_staff.html">Our staff</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any style elements that are common to each type of menuBlockOf4 I have applied to menuWrapper instead, removing them from menuBlockOf4. Specifically, I removed the "display" and "float" elements from menuBlockOf4 and placed them in menuWrapper.

```
.menuWrapper
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.menuBlockOf4
{
    width: 231px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

My understanding has been that the menuBlockOf4 should inherit the styling elements from menuWrapper. However, they do not, and instead it destroyed all of the styling and function.

Would anyone be able to explain what I might (or am) doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but generally speaking if you're going to refactor it you might as well adopt contemporary html5 conventions by introducing elements like `<nav>` and have each anchor as a list item in a `<ul>` and with as few elements and overrides as possible. Maybe even get super cool and introduce ARIA standards too. However, your question is still really broad amigo.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your feedback.

Yes, I was having difficulty homing in on the question, since I do not understand well enough what I am doing wrong. However, I think the immediate source of my confusion is my notion of the way inheritance works. Perhaps I should have asked more directly, why is menuBlockOf4 not inheriting the display and float elements from menuWrapper?

Comment: In this instance menuBlockof4 is redundant, as is the declaration for wrapper to be display: block since div is a block level element by default. If you wanted menuBlockof4 to inherit the properties of menuwrapper it's not automatic in this scenario and would need to be `.menuWrapper, .menuBlockof4 {...stuff...}` but (and this is not said out of rudeness, just honesty) but you might want to brush up on overall DOM & html semantics on top of your CSS skills. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your feedback and honesty. No offence taken. Yes, I think that my understanding of DOM semantics is more the problem than my understanding of CSS. The reason that I handled it in this way is that I have various menuBlockOfX, which share certain properties, but which have others that are unique. I created the divs with the notion of abstracting those shared properties from the unique, much as one might do with classes in C++, but I sense that HTML doesn't work that way.

Comment: @ChrisW. That said, menuBlockOf4 was required in my original functionality, since it was the only way that I knew to have a block of four sub-menu items open up to a certain height when a block of two would open to a different height. That is, I have menuBlockOf4:hover resize the block to accommodate four sub-menu items.

Comment: Makes sense and no worries, we're all here learning. You might look into an extension language like Sass, makes doing stuff with css so much quicker / easier.